# My dual boot machine will not connect to my Wifi, or Bluetooth

Tags: networking, drivers, sound, bluetooth

Desktop, custom built PC, Windows 11, and Ubuntu 22.04. TPLink Bluetooth dongle, Brostrend High Gain ac 1200 Wi-fi adapter.
The system said the Bluetooth is paired, but will not connect, also the system identifies my wireless network but will not connect. All of the latest drivers are installed. I can access the internet using my Ethernet through my Xfinity 5ghz router.
I use a Vizio wireless speaker, that connects just fine in Windows. I have no trouble connecting to my Wi-fi in Windows.
Most recent version of Ubuntu, with all valid updates installed. I've done a dozen searches looking for a solution, including this platform, and Youtube.
Anyone?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and edit the question to include the contents of wireless-info.txt

Comment: I did as you requested. 
Thanks

Comment: I don't see any results from the script in your question

Comment: my humble apologies, I followed the instructions to post the data at post,Ubuntu.com, and linked my question in that post.
 When I try to post it here in the comments, it says it is too long by a whole bunch of characters.

Comment: Do `cat wireless-info.txt|nc termbin.com` and post the termbin.com URL

Comment: That should have been `cat wireless-info.txt|nc termbin.com 9999`

Comment: https://termbin.com/rv5n1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No wifi adapter found ubuntu, I211](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1458803/no-wifi-adapter-found-ubuntu-i211)

Comment: The bluetooth might be hopeless

Comment: Fixed. Both are now working. Thank you!