# No wifi adapter found ubuntu, I211

Tags: drivers, wireless, 22.04, ethernet

I currently have ubuntu installed on my pc and Im trying to connect it to wifi using Intel I211 adapter, but even after downloading and installing drivers for I211 for linux system from Intel official site, system shows that adapter is unavailable and in wifi page the only message I see is - "No wifi adapter found".

I have installed different versions of drivers. I have reboot my pc a lot of times, reinstall all drivers (That was possible). (Adapter is working on windows) I really dont know what to do. Maybe its better to swich back to windows?

lspci output:

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 37
    Memory at fc800000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=32]
    Memory at fc820000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb
```

dmesg output:

```
[    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
[    1.127235] Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Linux Driver - version 5.13.7
[    1.127236] Copyright(c) 2007 - 2022 Intel Corporation.
[    1.212199] igb 0000:03:00.0: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Linux Driver
```

lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [1849:1539]
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb
04:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP [1022:1485]
```

```
matviiuk@matviiuk-desktop:~/Стільниця$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
matviiuk@matviiuk-desktop:~/Стільниця$ lsusb
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 0c45:7603 Microdia USB Keyboard
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 4e53:5406  USB OPTICAL MOUSE 
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 2357:0138 TP-Link 802.11ac NIC
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 2a70:f00e OnePlus Technology (Shenzhen) Co., Ltd. BE2029
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: please edit to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`

Comment: Okey here it is.

Comment: The i211 device is ethernet, not wifi. So far, we see no wifi device at all. Let's see: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you for info about ethernet. I added the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your wifi device: ID 2357:0138 TP-Link 802.11ac NIC

Please obtain a working internet connection with the perfectly working ethernet and open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall build-essential dkms bc git
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702.git
cd 88x2bu-20210702
sudo ./install-driver.sh
```

Reboot. You should be all set.